# Accredited school versus accredited degree

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, word-usage

Is it proper use of the adjective "accredited" to say or write "an accredited degree?"
I can't find it used in this manner in a dictionary and I feel like the adjective in this sense should be applied only to the school or institution.  In other words, one earns a degree from a accredited school, but not an accredited degree.  However, I see it all over the internet as "accredited degree" and the company for whom I'm copy-editing wishes to use it in that manner.  Just wondering which is correct..?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about language *per se*, but about educational institutions and the awarding of qualifications by educational institutions, which is, in any event, country dependent.

Answer (score 1):

If you graduated from an accredited school/university the degree is assumed to be accredited.  Therefore the "accredited degree" is redundant.

If you're apply for a job/writing a listing you could say "I have an accredited degree, but it would be considered odd.  Generally you list the degree and where it came from.  If the school isn't accredited, neither is the degree and vice-versa.